# Laravel 5.4 Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' on sync()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have `Playlist` and `Track` Many To Many relationship with additional `order` field:

```
Schema::create('playlist_track', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('playlist_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('track_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('order')->unsigned();

    $table->primary(['playlist_id', 'order']);
});
```

User can delete tracks from playlists and change an order. So this `sync` method is what I need:

```
        foreach ( $tracks as $key => $track ){
            $_tracks[ $track ] = [ 'order' => $key ];
        }

        $playlist->tracks()->sync( $_tracks );
```

But I get an error when trying to change an ordering of tracks:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3-0' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: update `playlist_track` set `order` = 0 where `playlist_id` = 3 and `track_id` = 1)
```

That's because i'm using composite primary key I guess... But I don't know how to make it works

**UPD**

This is dd( $_tracks )

```
array:2 [
  1 => array:1 [
    "order" => 0
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    "order" => 1
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's a pivot table, you can't define foreign key as primary, so remove this:

```
$table->primary(['playlist_id', 'order'])
```

Pivot table can have non unique `playlist_id` values, but with `->primary()` you're creating a constraint.

Comment: `$table->dropPrimary()` if you writing a migration to remove it at a later stage.

Answer (score 1):

Use an auto-increment, integer column as a primary key:

```
$table->increments('id');
```